# Отфильтровать по диапазону дат из связаной таблицы

Tags: python, django, django-orm

**Задача:**

Есть 2 таблицы: Марка автомобиля и Модель автомобиля

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Full name"), max_length=255, blank=True)

class CarModel(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="models_car")
    production_start = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    production_end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Для каждой модели авто есть год начала и окончания выпуска (конец не для всех есть).

От пользователя приходит год.

Необходимо вернуть марки автомобилей для которых есть хотя бы одна модель с годом выпуска, полученным от пользователя.

---

Т.е. по сути необходима функция которая на вход получает число, а на выходе отдает QuerySet из Manufacturer.

---

**Пример:**

```
Manufacturer:
    id    title
    ===========
    1     Audi
    2     BMW

Model:
    mfa_id     start      end
    =========================
    1          1932       1960
    1          1980       2001
    2          1977       2014
    2          2004       ----
```

От пользователя приходит год = **1954**.

Нужно вернуть только **Audi**, тк у **BMW** нет модели 1954 года выпуска.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
def get_mfa(year):
    year = date(int(year), 1, 1)
    cm = CarModel.objects.filter(Q(production_end__gte=d) | Q(production_end=None), production_start__lte=d) 

    return Manufacturer.objects.filter(models_car__in=cm).distinct()
```

Answer (score 3):

.Здравствуйте, почитайте про вложенные запросы , думаю все станет понятно. Кроме того с одного запроса можно обратиться к двум таблицам сразу.

Comment: Т.е. первым запросом получаем все модели соответствующие году, из них получаем соответствующие им марки?

Comment: нужно  проверить в какой из диапазонов  лет/годов)  входит год указанный пользователем и на основании этого выбрать mfa_id  а там уже выбирать title

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли. Даже странно, что сам не догадался.